# Hot-deploy JSPs in web-fragment using Eclipse and Tomcat (Servlet 3.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I have a project set up like this:

```
/parent
 /core
  /src/main/
   /resources/META-INF/
      web-fragment.xml
      /resources/jsp/
        fragment.jsp
   /java/
     FragmentTest.java
 /web
  /src/main/
    /webapp/
      /WEB-INF/web.xml
      /jsps/
        parent.jsp
    /java/
      ParentTest.java
```

the 'core' compiles to a .jar within the .war.

However, when deploying this to Tomcat, with debug enabled, I can edit parent.jsp and it will hot deploy, however if I update fragment.jsp then it will not, and I have to rebuild/redeploy/etc.

However, any changes to the .java in either project will hot-deploy successfully.

Is anyone aware of any configurations, etc. that may be missing to get web-fragment JSPs to hot deploy?

Thanks!

Comment: Also listed as an eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=414440

Comment: Eclipse is doing the deployment itself, not Maven, right? Tomcat is launched using Debug On Server?

Comment: @nitind that's correct. Although same-ish behaviour exhibits on a Maven server last time I tried

Comment: did you find an alternative way to do this?

Comment: I never did I'm afraid. Moved away from web fragments to Spring resources.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation. I have **test-web** (your **parent**) and **test-web-fragment** (your **core**). I resolved them in the following way:

In the **/test-web -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly** I added the **Fileset** rule that points to **/test-web-fragment/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources** (See the screenshots below).

When I change something in a page from fragment, the eclipse builder copies it to **/test-web/src/main/webapp**. After that I do a right click to test-web in app server and click **Full Publish** and I have to the server my changes. This trick I use in the development mode. When I make the build for production I use maven, without this rule.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1):

Your project structure confuses me a bit. We always place JSPs in `/src/main/webapp` and sub folders therein. I can very well imagine this to be the source of your problem.

Comment: Hi Marcel - yes, that's how we used to have it. However, we need to build a few customized .wars, so we want to move all the JSPs into a common dependency (using web fragments). In this case, JSPs should live in META-INF/resources/ in the .jar

Comment: Ah - I see what you're saying, our JSPs in the war are under webapp, edited my question

Comment: I don't want to 'bump' this question, but I have the same problem. Any solution for this?

Comment: @cs.tropic Using JRebel helps a little, but I can't get my employer to pay for it :(

Comment: @MikeH, does your employer know how much time you already spent/wasted on this issue? And how this compares to the cost of a JRebel license? Seriously, if my employer didn't pay for it I'd either buy it myself or leave. Can't imagine working without JRebel anymore.

Comment: @MarcelStör - working on it :)

JRebel isn't perfect at dealing with web fragments though. Seems like they're not an overly popular feature, which I don't quite understand. The ability to spread your static resources around modules seems hugely useful!

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to hot deploy both JSPs and Java files if you do the following:

Separate your web fragment project into two different projects and reference them from your main Web applications:

- One containing all your Java source files (this project has to be a Web Fragment). This will be packed as a JAR file and you will be able to hot deploy Java files as you're currently doing
- Another project, a Dynamic Web Project, containing all your static / JSP files under the WebContent folder. This will be deployed unpacked and will allow you to hot deploy everything under WebContent folder

There could be a better option than this one, but at least you will be able to work properly until you find something better.